# With Apache, Rewrite traffic to a folder and yet redirect all traffic from that folder

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that is currently migrating from an old CMS to a new one (Laravel). Only some languages of the website have been moved to Laravel. So basicaly, my root folder of the vhost has something like this:

```
[D] staticContentDirectory1
[D] staticContentDirectory2
...
[D] oldCmsDirectory1
[D] oldCmsDirectory2
...
[D] oldCmsDirectoryN
[D] public
[F] index-of-the-old-cms-still-in-use.php
```

I have a `.htaccess` file that redirects everything that is not handled by the old CMS or in a static content directory to Laravel and looks something like this :

```
RewriteRule ^((?!staticContentDirectory1|staticContentDirectory2|public)(.*))$ public/$1 [L]
```

There is also a `.htaccess` in public, from Laravel, to handle its stuff.

So far, everything is working perfectly fine and we were pretty happy with the result (given the initial constraints).

We discovered an issue though. Somehow, Google managed to discover that `/public` exists and crawled it, which lead to the URL with a `/public/` inside, which since then had created `/public/public/` URLs (which, fortunately, returns a 500 error and avoided an infinity of URLs).

Before fixing the CMS and `robots.txt` we tried to fix that by rewriting/redirecting traffic from `/public` to `/`.

A lot of things were tried, a lot of failures happened, almost all in an infinite loop of redirects.

Because every Apache module seems to do its stuff on his own, mixing `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteRule` failed. `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` were either an infinite redirect or totally ignored.

**TL;DR: I'm asking for help now : how can one have a RewriteRule to a `/folder` and yet redirect all traffic from that folder to the root.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid a redirect loop you need to differentiate between a direct request for the `/public` subdirectory and a request that has been *internally rewritten* to the `/public` subdirectory (which is what your directive above does).

There are several ways to do this. One way is to check the `THE_REQUEST` server variable, which contains the initial request header (eg. `GET /public/whatever HTTP/1.1`) as sent from the client and does not change when the URL is rewritten.

Try the following... as a general rule, external redirects should go before internal rewrites, so the following rule should go near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory (not the `.htaccess` file in the document root):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /public
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

For any *direct* request that start `/public/<whatever>` then redirect to `/<whatever>`. The preceding `RewriteCond` directive ensures that only direct requests are processed.

The `RewriteRule` directive might look a bit odd at first (as if it perhaps redirects to itself), but this is because the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path *less the directory-prefix* of where the `.htaccess` file is located. So, given a request for `/public/<whatever>`, the `$1` backreference only captures `<whatever>`. So redirects back to `/<whatever>`.

Note that this is currently a temporary (302) redirect. Change this to a `301` only when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser, so can make testing problematic if there is an error.

> mixing `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteRule` failed

Since directives belong to different modules (mod_alias vs mod_rewrite), they execute at different times during the request, regardless of their apparent order in the config file (mod_rewrite usually runs first). So mixing these directives can indeed result in conflicts. However, `RedirectMatch` does not give you the control that's required in this instance.

Comment: It works perfectly !